# Regex to find named capturing groups with Go programming language

Tags: regex, go

I'm looking for a regex to find named capturing groups in (other) regex strings.

Example: I want to find `(?P<country>m((a|b).+)n)`, `(?P<city>.+)` and `(?P<street>(5|6)\. .+)` in the following regex:

```
/(?P<country>m((a|b).+)n)/(?P<city>.+)/(?P<street>(5|6)\. .+)
```

I tried the following regex to find the named capturing groups:

```
var subGroups string = `(\(.+\))*?`
var prefixedSubGroups string = `.+` + subGroups
var postfixedSubGroups string = subGroups + `.+`
var surroundedSubGroups string = `.+` + subGroups + `.+`
var capturingGroupNameRegex *regexp.RichRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(
    `(?U)` + 
    `\(\?P<.+>` + 
    `(` +   prefixedSubGroups + `|` + postfixedSubGroups + `|` + surroundedSubGroups + `)` + 
    `\)`)
```

`?U` makes greedy quantifiers(`+` and `*`) non-greedy, and non-greedy quantifiers (`*?`) greedy. Details in the [Go regex documentation](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax).

But it doesn't work because parenthesis are not matched correctly.

Comment: hello, I came across this post and I'm trying to understand what (?P<country>m((a|b).+)n) is trying to do. Is "?P" Go syntax to use when defining named subgroups. Any easy-to-understand website you can recommend to get more details about this? I'm just learning Go so any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Matching arbitrarily nested parentheses correctly is not possible with regular expressions because arbitrary (recursive) nesting cannot be described by a regular language.

Some modern regex flavor do support recursion (Perl, PCRE) or balanced matching (.NET), but Go is not one of them ([the docs explicitly say](http://code.google.com/p/re2/wiki/Syntax) that Perl's `(?R)` construct is not supported by the [RE2 library that Go's regex package appears to be based on](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#pkg-overview)). You need to build a recursive descent parser, not a regex.

Comment: Just to clarify: the Go "regexp" package _doesn't use_ the RE2 library.

Comment: It does - just follow the link

Comment: OK, it doesn't actually use that library, but it accepts the same syntax.